# display loading image until all data gets loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Right now i am simply giving a definite time interval after which the loading image disappears but i want to place a loading image which will be display until all the content in the background is not fully loaded.

current code

```
#loadingImgDIv{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:14;
}

<script>
setTimeout("removeLoadingImg()",5000);
function removeLoadingImg(){
//using css display:hidden; attribute on #loadingImgDiv using javascript
}
</script>
```

But this is not the right way to do it...so please help me

Comment: how do you load the content? Are you making some calls to get some data?

Comment: why isnt it the right way?

Comment: Loading means ajax or direct html or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
spinner.show()
$.get('/api')
  .success(successCb)
  .fail(failCb)
  .always(function(){
    //...
    spinner.dismiss()
  })
```

Comment: thanks but can you say how to use it with pure javascript code without using jquery

Comment: @HarshKanakhara You tagged the question [jQuery], indicating that jQuery answers are acceptable.

Comment: #Boann you are right but my first priority is to develop code using pure javascript

Comment: I do not suggest use pure JS for AJAX. Anyway, you have to create your own XmlHttpRequest wrapper with similar syntax for this. There are lot of different lightweight libraries with similar syntax.